# How to detect addresses with no number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `address` with thousands of addresses, most of them have a number but lot of addresses have no number, the addresses are like this:

```
- streetname 4
- streetname 8
- streetname 4/5
- streetname
```

how do i detect the fields like 'streetname' having no number.
I have tried with:

```
REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$';
```

or isANumber() but none gives the right result

Comment: Is that your sample data? There's a lot of ways a street address can be expressed, the "streetname ##" is just one of them.

Comment: in my table the addresses are like this:  "streetname ##"

Comment: If what you're ultimately trying to do is to parse an address, and this is not a learning exercise like a homework assignment, I would **strongly** suggest that you go with an existing solution like the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518210/where-is-a-good-address-parser) for more details. There are so many different ways that addresses are articulated, that you're going to spend the rest of your career programming around every edge case you encounter.

Comment: @BobKaufman You're not supposed to tell him that now... wait till the end of his career to point it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
address rlike '^[^0-9]*$'
```

Comment: thank you @Gordon Linoff this give the wished result

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove the number from the end

```
TRIM(TRAILING '1234567890 ' FROM fieldname)
```

SO

```
WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '1234567890 ' FROM fieldname) <> TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM fieldname)
```

have numbers and

```
WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '1234567890 ' FROM fieldname) = TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM fieldname)
```

don't.

Comment: This would assume that the OP is looking for numbers only at the end of the address.  If so, it is a clever solution.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff - I thought that was what the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you wnat select the rows that  contain number

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_column REGEXP '[0-9]';
```

or if you wnat the rows that not contain

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE your_column NOT REGEXP '[0-9]';
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff   yes..correct   i have update the answer