# Is there an open source address-parser(locations) algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for a good address-parser that could parser any free texts and generate a tokenized output:

If you have something in C# would be helpful, but has no problem if in another language.

---

Example 1:

Free text entry: **23 Street n. 213 new york ny**

Output: Street: **23 Street**, Number: **213**, City: **New York**, State: **NY**

---

Example 2:

Free text entry: **new york**

Output: City: **New York**

---

Example 3:

Free text entry: 12345

Output: ZIP: 12345

---

Example 4:

Free text entry: **Auckley Fake Street New York New York**

Output: Street: **Auckley Fake Street**, City: **New York**, State: **New York**

Comment: Consider Brazilian addresses patterns, or something like that.

Comment: There are some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Perl solution that seems to address your address problem:

http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Geo-StreetAddress-US/Geo/StreetAddress/US.pm.html

And here is JGeoCoder, a Java solution :

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JGEOCODER/Parser

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to take advantage of remote services, you can try [Google's Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). I think it provides the detail you require while accepting free form input.

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't catch the essence of your question. The Geocoding API cannot specifically identify **what** was typed in (for example, whether it was a ZIP code, an address, etc...)