# Parsing location string

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, geolocation, geocoding

I'm trying to guess the location (non US; could be street, postal code, neighborhood or city)

The user typed in a search box and I was wondering if you guys could give me some tips on how to go about this.

I currently have a 5 tables in my database:

`Address (address and postal code fields)

Neighborhoods (neighborhood field)

Cities (city field)

States (abbreviation and state fields)

Countries (only one row at the moment, so I'd just ignore it)`

The only fields I know the format would be state abbreviations which would be two chars and postal codes that would be 00000-000 or 00000000.

How would I deal with duplicate postal codes, addresses, neighborhoods and city names?

I know I could go the Gmaps route but I'm thinking it wouldn't play very nice with my database set..

What do you guys suggest?

Comment: You also know that numbers that aren't postal codes are parts of a street address.

Comment: This thread may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get into troubles reinventing the wheel.

I would use Geocoder implementation for this problem, see this tutorial
http://www.phpriot.com/articles/google-maps-geocoding/6