# How Does iPhone's Email app recognize an Address?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have been Playing around with my iPhone and i recently realized that the Email App of iPhone can recognize if a line within an Email represents an address. Interestingly enough this works with many address Patterns. I tried USA , Germany, France and Spain. In all the cases the address was highlighted as a blue link just as a phone number would be.
So my question is what is the algorithm behind this address detection?

Comment: Actually what do u want to implement, Specify clearly. Or you want only that how to detect mail-id.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? The responses below simply point to black boxes rather than algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `UIDataDetectorTypes` in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html). You'll find a `UIDataDetectorTypeAddress` that detects strings formatted as addresses. 
You could then add this detector type to a `UITextView`.

Comment: I did not mean Email Addresses.I meant Location Addresses.How Can iPhone recognize all types of location Addresses, USA , Spain, france ,....

Comment: `UIDataDetectorTypeAddress` will detect these adresses (there is no 'email' in 'UIDataDetectorTypeAddress'.

Comment: Thanks Tilo, but i have not gotten the answer to my question yet.There must be a way that this UIDataDetectorTypeAddress thing detects an address, no matter which country it belongs to.
That's what i want to know.I don't need any implementation , just a logic how to do it.

Comment: Sure, it is done _somehow_, but Apple most likely won't tell you how they did it. There are companies out there offering this kind of service (for money). You'll find a possible answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16444/184245

Answer (score 1):

You can set  `theObj.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAddress;`

Or you can implement like this

```
UITextView *theObj;
theObj = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 10, 225, 65)];
theObj.text = @"sample@mail.com";
theObj.editable = NO;
theObj.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAddress;
[myview theObj];
```

Comment: I did not mean Email Addresses.I meant Location Addresses.How Can iPhone recognize all types of location Addresses, USA , Spain, france ,....