# How can I parse an address into its individual components?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, html-agility-pack

I've been tasked with building a parser that will parse a particular web-page, so that our employees can do a bulk import of their user data into their web-site with our company.

I've utilized the *HtmlAgilityPack* to parse the page, I've correlated the `table row` and `table data` to be pushed into properties in my `Map` class.

However one *column* is causing me alot of grief.  The **Address** column, is the thorn in my side for an assortment of reasons.

*Sample Data:*

```
6313 SW 203rd Ave <br> Portland, OR 97224
16600 Lomita Way <br> El Dorado Hills, CA 95762
PO Box #42 <br> Hampton Bays, NY 11946
```

Each one of those addresses is wrapped like so (Obviously the addresses may vary based on the customer whom we are importing users for):

```
<tr>
     <td> 6313 SW 203rd Ave <br> Portland, OR 97224 </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to implement a **Regular Expression** to split this in the proper area, so it may be assigned to the correlating properties:

```
public string Unit { get; set; }
public string Street { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string Zip { get; set; }
```

However the addresses don't provide much to anchor off of:

*Issue One:*
If I anchor off the `<br>` then I'm only separating the lines.  Doesn't fully split into proper segments.

*Issue Two:*
Same issue with the individual comma.

*Issue Three:* 
If I anchor to numeric values, for the Zip may be invalid for Canada and may split incorrectly based on street name.

**What is the best way to separate items for an address? With Regex?**

Comment: What is Batman ? is it some kind of Library ?

Comment: StackOverflow has been down for the last couple of minutes. This is the undeniable proof that you have unleashed the destruction of the known universe by attempting to [**Parse HTML with Regex**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/643085).

Comment: Oh no. You're trying to [parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Oh nooooooͮ̄̏̒ͪ͂͏͉̼ͅȱ̖̻̺̳̬̬̲ͩ̾́o̭̰̬̯̦̻ͣ̃ͪ͆̾ͅǫ̴̱̑ͯ̏ͮ̃ͣ̈́̆͘ö̳̱̹͖́̎͒̐o̠̅͑ͨ̕͝ǫ̴̛͔̥̝͈͇͍̖͍̝̥̘̟̔̋̔̎ͣͦ̒̽̈́̈ͭͪ͒͂͐̋͋̾o͒̋͊̌ͪ̉̑ͦ͒̊̆͂̕͟҉̬̺͔̭͇̱̤͈̮̲̪̲͕̖̝̳̣͕o̵̢͈̬̱͇̣̲͓̯͕̜̩͖͕̱̤̔ͬͫ͆ͨͤo̷̯̟̻̣͉͖͕̹̱̬̳͕̼͎̪̊̍̎̌̍̈́͌̇͑̂͠

Comment: @HighCore Thanks, I'm not really parsing HTML with `Regex` per say.  I'm using the `HtmlAgilityPack` to do the parse, but I am trying to separate the parsed values returned as a `string`.  As the `HtmlAgilityPack` will return the data value for the column for me to separate.

Comment: @Greg: (nitpick) It's "per se" (Latin for "by itself") and has nothing to do with saying something...

Comment: @TimPietzcker I know, the red squiggly bugs my OCD out, so I changed it so I couldn't see the line.

Comment: Not fool proof, but perhaps you can keep the `<br>`, detect that and use as indicator of street address, then take the rest, split in `,` to get your city, then space to get state and zip?  Obviously your first part of *<br>*  will give you the unit and street by taking first space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the `Address` field was quite painful to parse.  However I did manage to parse the data based on my particular requirements.

- The `Address` always has a `<br>` between the Street & City.

So I did the following:

```
var splitBasedOnHTML = Regex.Split(column[2], @"\br<br>");
```

The `column[]` contains my address in `index two`.  So after that call, it will automatically position my Unit and Street in `Index Zero`.  The City, State, and Zip will be located `Index One`.

So I did another split, to break the City, State, and Zip like this:

```
var splitBasedOnSpace = splitBasedOnHtml[1].Split(' ');
```

After that I now end up with the following:

```
6313 SW 203rd Ave // splitBasedOnHtml[0]
Portland, // splitBasedonSpace[0]
OR // splitBasedOnSpace[1]
97224 // splitBasedOnSpace[2]
```

So I simply mapped my properties to those individual array index's.

This solution makes the **assumption that the Unit is apart of the Street**, which become an okay sacrifice as the data is being imported into another web-site and can be modified by particular people later on.

That is how I solved the parse issues, this solution may not be viable for others in this boat but hopefully this is a nice alternative or points in a good direction.  What the method looks like:

```
    public static Map AddressMapper(IList<string> column)
    {
        var map = new Map();
        var splitBasedOnHTML = Regex.Split(column[2], @"\b<br>");
        var splitBasedOnSpace = splitBasedOnHTML[1].Split(' ');

        map.Street = splitBasedOnHTML[0];
        map.City = splitBasedOnSpace[0].Replace(@",", " ");
        map.State = splitBasedOnSpace[1];
        map.Zip = spliteBasedOnSpace[2];

        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Parsing addresses is hard; really hard.
There is no truely uniform format for addresses, especially across country borders.
It's highly unlikely that you will be able to do this using a single RegEx.

See this other post for a few examples and a more in-depth explanation.
[How to parse freeform street/postal address out of text, and into components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components)

Answer (score 2):

There's a limit to what can be done with regular expressions, however here's an example that assumes your addresses always respects this format. If you cannot ensure that your addresses will respect a specific format (enforced by your domain), you will have to rely on some more complex solutions like what's discussed in the other answer.

Also have a look at [Parse usable Street Address, City, State, Zip from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string)

**EDIT: I'm sorry, I forgot this was a C# question... but you get the picture.**

```
var parseAddress = (function (rx) {
  return function parseAddress(html) { 
      var matches = html.match(rx);
      return {
          unit: matches[1],
          street: matches[2],
          city: matches[3],
          state: matches[4],
          zip: matches[5]
      };
  };
})(/^(\d*)\s*(.+?)\s*<br>\s*(.+?),\s*(.+?)\s*(\d+)$/);

parseAddress('6313 SW 203rd Ave <br> Portland, OR 97224');
//Object {unit: "6313", street: "SW 203rd Ave", city: "Portland", state: "OR", zip: "97224"}
```

Comment: This doesn't accept ZIP+5. This doesn't accept apartment numbers. This doesn't accept addresses with "B" in them (i.e. "432B SW 203rd Ave"). This doesn't accept fractional addresses (i.e. "432 1/2 SW 203rd Ave").

Comment: @CanSpice It's just an example of what could be achieved with regular expressions. I do not pretend that what is shown is a great address parser.

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the html tags, there is powerful open-source library [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) that fits for this use case very nicely. There are bindings to different programming languages. Libpostal is a C library for parsing/normalizing street addresses around the world using statistical NLP and open data. The goal of this project is to understand location-based strings in every language, everywhere.

I have created a simple Docker image with Python binding pypostal you can spin off and try very easily [pypostal-docker](https://github.com/WojtylaCZ/pypostal-docker)