# How to convert an address string to an address dictionary

Tags: macos, geocoding, addressbook

I extract addresses from text using OSX data detectors. This gives me address strings like “*1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA*”.
In order to put such addresses into the OSX address book, I have to convert them to a dictionary with keys like "*Street*", "*City*", "*Country*" etc.
I know that there is a function that does the reverse: `ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(...)`, but I need it the other way.
The only way I know this can be done (and is, of course, total overkill) is to send the address string to a `CLGeocoder`, which returns the coordinates of the address, and send then the coordinates again for reverse geocoding, which returns a placemark containing the address dictionary.
There must be an easier way to do this.
**EDIT**:
I learned by now,
1) that this problem is really complicated, and is really done best by using a geocoding server, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string),
2) that it is enough to contact the geocoding server only once: When an address string is sent there, an address directory is sent back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a data detector with type `NSTextCheckingTypeAddress`, the returned matches should provide an [addressComponents](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTextCheckingResult/addressComponents) dictionary.
That dictionary contains all the keys you mentioned.

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeAddress error:nil];
NSString* addressString = @"Apple, 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA";
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:addressString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, addressString.length)];
for(NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches)
{
    if(match.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeAddress)
    {
        NSDictionary* addressComponents = [match addressComponents];
        NSLog(@"Address Dictionary:%@", addressComponents);
    }
}
```

The above snippet returns the following for the input string:

```
Address Dictionary:{
    City = Cupertino;
    State = CA;
    Street = "1 Infinite Loop";
}
```

A fully featured address string would result in values for the following keys:

```
NSTextCheckingNameKey
NSTextCheckingJobTitleKey
NSTextCheckingOrganizationKey
NSTextCheckingStreetKey
NSTextCheckingCityKey
NSTextCheckingStateKey
NSTextCheckingZIPKey
NSTextCheckingCountryKey
NSTextCheckingPhoneKey
NSTextCheckingAirlineKey
NSTextCheckingFlightKey
```