# How to get links ranges from UITextView in Swift

Tags: uitextview, nsattributedstring, ios14, xcode12

I have a chat app with the `UITextView` with a dynamic text (comes from the server or is typed by the user). I needed to detect all types of links, and the `UITextView` does a great job in detecting phone numbers, addresses, hyperlinks and calendar events. Where `UITextView` falls short is styling, there are multiple problems there:

1. The address links are not colored with the `tintColor` or with the color from `linkTextAttributes` property, or using the `appearance()` proxy.
2. All of the links are underlined by default.
3. Some of the links are colored properly, but I fail to see a pattern why certain links are omitted (looks like it may have something to do with the word wrap).
4. When setting custom `underlineStyle` attribute, the text simply disappears.

So I thought the best thing to do would be to still use the `UITextView` for detecting the links, but then create my own attributed string and style everything the way I want. For this I need the ranges for the links, but I can't find the way to get them.

I tried this:

```
open func enumerateAttributes(in enumerationRange: NSRange, options opts: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions = [], using block: ([NSAttributedString.Key : Any], NSRange, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)
```

But there are never any `.link` elements, nor any underline attributes if I look for them. So the question is, is there a way to get the link ranges from the `UITextView` somehow? Or perhaps there is a way to reliably style the links that I'm missing?

Comment: Phone Numbers, addresses etc, there are detected using the Data Detector mechanism. See there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41077174/extracting-address-elements-from-a-string-using-nsdatadetector-in-swift-3-0 to enumerate I think you'll be able to work with the `match.range` then ;)

Comment: @Larme awesome, this will allow me to forget the UITextView all together and style everything myself. If you write this in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the Phone Numbers, addresses etc, you are in fact using the [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector?language=objc).

That's what you in fact set in InterfaceBuilder there:

[image]

Then:

```
let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.address, .link, .phoneNumber, .date]
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
matches.forEach {
    guard let range = Range($0.range, in: text) else { return }
    let sub = String(text[range])
    print(sub)
}
```

Comment: Do we need the Authorization for Calendar or Reminder App? if the iOS shows the action controller on tapping detected links? This is the default behavior. I am not using any API to create events or reminders.