# Separate mailing address into cells in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there a formula I can use in Excel to take a mailing address and separate it out into cells for Street, City, State and Zip?
I use to use a bulk mail program to do it, but don't have access to it anymore. The problem is that the addresses can vary slightly, some might have a 5-digit zip, some might have the 5-digit+4, some addresses have commas, some don't.

**UPDATE:**
Here is some sample data. They aren't always tab delimited as the full list is made up from several others

```
0000 PENN AVE S     | RICHFIELD         | MN    | 55423-3629
00 W 51ST ST        | MINNEAPOLIS       | MN    | 55410-2110
000 COLUMBIA DRIVE  | EAGAN             | MN    | 55121-4202
000 - 3RD AVE SW    | FARIBAULT         | MN    | 55021
000 MENDOTA HGTS RD | MENDOTA HEIGHTS   | MN    | 55120-1426
0000 NICOLLET AVE S | RICHFIELD         | MN    | 55423
00 SUMMIT AVE       | SAINT PAUL        | MN    | 55102
00 KELLOGG BLVD  W  | SAINT PAUL        | MN    | 55102
```

Comment: Can you include an example of what some of the data looks like that you are working with?

Comment: Is this text data in a .txt, in a cell in excel, where is it?

Comment: Check this related question out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string